# How do I use multiple precisions in printf()?

Tags: c, string, formatting, char, printf

Looking at the information under the heading "[Precision can be omitted or be any of:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf)".

The example: `printf("%.*s", 3, "abcdef");`  works, outputting:`abc` (truncating the rest of the string.)

Now, I would like to have a string with multiple parameters formatted (truncated):

```
printf("%.*s, %.*s", 3, 3, "abcdef", "xyz123");
```

but the program crashes.

What is the correct syntax?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should change order?

```
printf("%.*s, %.*s", 3, "abcdef", 3, "xyz123");
```

By the way you can hardcode precision if you don't need it as a variable:

```
printf("%.3s, %.3s", "abcdef", "xyz123");
```

(Stephen Canon kindly corrected the typo)

Comment: How did this get 5 upvotes? It doesn't work.  It gives warnings when compiling, and segfaults when it runs.  The hardcoded one doesn't work either.

Comment: Jack, I edited your format strings so that this compiles and works properly.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo based just to have quickly copied and pasted the other code, sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to do it like this:

```
printf("%.*s, %.*s", 3, "abcdef", 3, "xyz123");
```

The format arguments should be in the same order as the format specifiers.

Comment: Fixed (I had copied the line from the original post, didn't notice the improperly-placed double quotes).

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%.*s, %.*s",3,"abcdef",3,"xyz123");
```